# Exe file not working outside of the bin its created c#

Tags: c#, uwp, exe, tesseract

So I have two projects, Background and FirstUWP that I am creating together. Background has ScreenAnalyzation.cs as its file and creates an EXE file called scrren.exe when compiled. I am attempting to use that EXE in my FirstUWP asset folder so I can call on it using RunFullTrust. However, that EXE, once taken out of the Background folder, completely breaks. I can see it open for a second in the Task Manager, before it crashes. To be clear, I am moving the scrren.exe file from C:\Users\dan\source\repos\Scrren\Scrren\bin\Debug\scrren.exe into C:\Users\dan\source\repos\FIrstUWP\FIrstUWP\Assets\scrren.exe. However, it just does not work. Are there certain files I am forgetting to include alongside the scrren.exe? It takes advantage of tesseract, but I assumed that gets baked into the EXE file. Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: you will need to copy the tesseract dlls too

Comment: @pm100 do you have an idea of how I could go about doing that? Should I put all of those files in a folder and then add the entire folder over to the assets of the UWP?